# AWS ECS Fargate: How to Configure SSL with Traefik

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, traefik, aws-fargate

I'm using AWS Fargate and I've switched from AWS AELB to Traefik v1.7 and my load times got a little bit faster and it's the best choice cost-wise. I installed Traefik in a Docker container on an EC2 in my VPC.

But as you know, managing SSL certificates with AWS LB is easy as a pie. Traefik is easy too but I'm having problems setting it up.

Dashboard is showing up, my configuration is correct, all the forwarding stuff is alright and when I enter to my sub-domain, my site is there. New deployments show up correctly etc. everything is fine. But SSL never works. I tried with both Let's Encrypt and my custom wildcard domain. I've tried httpChallenge and dnsChallenge and still, not working. Let's Encrypt generates the certificate but doesn't attach it to my ECS deployments that has configured subdomain. There are few documents that I found online and they're not talking about this issue. Official documents are not that detailed as well. My problem is specifically with ECS I assume. I might be missing something in my traefik.toml or AWS ECS Task definition docker labels as well, I don't know.

Here is my current traefik.toml file shows my config with my own wildcard certificate. Like I say at some point Let's Encrypt variations were present as well, written exactly the way in the Traefik Docs. but for now use this as a reference:

```
# Entrypoints configuration

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/traefik/MYCERT.pem"
      keyFile = "/etc/traefik/MYPRIVATEKEY.pem"

# ECS Provider

[ecs]
#cluster = "default"
clusters = ["MYCLUSTERNAME"]
watch = true
domain = "MYDOMAIN.com"
autoDiscoverClusters = false
refreshSeconds = 15
exposedByDefault = true

region = "eu-central-1"
accessKeyID = "MYACCESSKEY"
secretAccessKey = "MYSECRETKEY"
```

My Docker Labels in belonged container on ECS Task Definition:

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.com
traefik.enable=true
traefik.backend=MY-PROJECT-BE-DUMMY-TEXT
traefik.port=80
traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
```

Here is how I run Traefik container in my EC2:

```
docker run -d \
--name traefik-lb \
--restart unless-stopped \
-v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml \
-v $PWD/MYCERT.pem:/etc/traefik/MYCERT.pem \
-v $PWD/MYPRIVATEKEY.pem:/etc/traefik/MYPRIVATEKEY.pem \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 80:80 \
traefik
```

Part of the logs:

```
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="No tls.defaultCertificate given for https: using the first item in tls.certificates as a fallback."
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) *.MYDOMAIN.com,MYDOMAIN.com"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc00000c4c0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Address::443 TLS:0xc0001ad440 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc00000ccc0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) *.MYDOMAIN.com,MYDOMAIN.com"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Preparing server traefik &{Address::8080 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc00000cce0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Starting provider configuration.ProviderAggregator {}"
time="2019-10-01T08:31:00Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :8080"
```

What could be causing this issue? All I want from Traefik is to map that acknowledged wildcard domain and assign it to my deployments so when I enter subdomain.domain.com, I see my domain.com SSL on top.

Thanks.